# After Installation Issues

Tags: unity, drivers, gnome, nvidia

I have been playing with Ubuntu since 8.04 and have several servers running 64bit 12.04LTS full time.  I have used desktop on and off over this time period but have never committed any machine to running desktop full time.  I have a HP dv9000 with AMD Athlon x2 and NVidia which I have used with Vista, Ubuntu Studio, 7, and now trying to get 13.10 to run on it without success.  After trying both the 64bit and 32bit versions I decided to try 32bit Ubuntu Gnome.  It is running ok, but is still somewhat glitchy.

After my first attempt, I did some digging and found out that there are some driver-related issues and would need to install the NVidia drivers.  During the next attempt to run Ubuntu Unity I would <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to get to a terminal and install the drivers.  Reboot, and try to go in to Unity.  It would "work" for a short amount of time, usually less than 5 minutes, then everything would freeze on the desktop but the mouse.  I couldn't get anything to happen or access a terminal.  The only way to get out of the situation was to force-restart the system.

I have been playing with Gnome version for the last 2 days and, while it sometimes freezes, it seems to run far more reliably.  I can open multiple programs and switch between them, use email, the Internet, all things I was unable to do under Unity.

So, I decided to install Unity on the working Gnome install and, no surprise, it started having the exact same problems when I logged in to it.  However, the Gnome environment was the same as before.

This machine was running Win 7 fine before I decided to make it my first full-time Ubuntu  Desktop machine, so I am leaning towards a hardware compatibility issue between Ubuntu 13.10 and the dv9000.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands on virtual console(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>),

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

You might get back to your original desktop